# Why is my Set of Roles throwing Unsupporred UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple User Entity that has Roles ( Other fields are omitted for brevity )

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

And a method for adding this roles

```
public void addRole(Role role) {
    roles.add(role);
}
```

Constructor

```
public User(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.roles = Set.of(Role.USER);
}
```

When I add a Role to a User in my Tests for a fake UserDetails bean UnsupportedOperationException happens.
I can see it in debug mode that is being thrown from ImmutableCollections class.

```
User adminUserEntity = new User("Bob", "admin@gmail.com", "password");
adminUserEntity.addRole(Role.ADMIN); // Exception
```

Full exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in class path resource [com/grad/restaurant/TestConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]: Factory method 'userDetailsService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]: Factory method 'userDetailsService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
```

Full UserDetails ( Pretty sure that it is not closely related to the question )

```
@Bean
@Primary
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    User basicUserEntity = new User("John", "user@gmail.com", "password");
    User adminUserEntity = new User("Bob", "admin@gmail.com", "password");
    adminUserEntity.addRole(Role.ADMIN);

    AuthenticatedUser basicUser = new AuthenticatedUser(basicUserEntity);
    AuthenticatedUser adminUser = new AuthenticatedUser(adminUserEntity);

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(basicUser, adminUser);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the stack trace.

Comment: @Turing85 added a stack trace. In debug mode I can clearly see that the exception is being thrown from  ImmutableCollections.class when I add something to roles.

Comment: How do you initialize `private Set<Role> roles;` in class `User`?

Comment: [`Set::of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)) returns an [unmodifiable Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable).

Comment: @Turing85 omg, thank you for the help... I've just understood that Set.of() returns an Unmodifiable Set..

Comment: What you have posted is not the full exception stacktrace.